# One IP address does not respond to ping

Tags: ip, ping, subnet, dmz

Ok so here's the situation: I have a DMZ subnet, x.x.x.x, and this IP address( x.x.x.63 | 255.255.255.0 | gateway x.x.x.1) **fails every ping request** by any other device in the network but still works and navigates.

This is the network configuration: the firewall manages the DMZ which is connected to a VLAN controlled by the router. A laptop is then connected to it with the network configurations stated above.It has no DHCP configured as I need everything to be static.

I've already checked for IP conflict. Setting a different device with this IP address still has the same problems, while giving it a different address (ex. x.x.x.87) and sending ping request works fine. So I suppose it's not a device related problem. The tracert (traceroute) command fails at the very first step.

Went throug and checked the router settings but didn't find anything that seems to be blocking this IP, also in the ARP table this subnet is nowhere to be found.

My colleagues managing the firewall said that they didn't find anything related to this in the configuration.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Comment: We need more information in order to help you.  Please edit your question to include a simple diagram, the types and configurations of the relevant devices.  Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Also, di you check the arp table on the router?

Comment: If you subnetted 255.255.255.0 you may end up with a .63 being an unusable address.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you device has a host based firewall that simply blocks all inbound connections, including ICMP.

One other thing to check is that all the devices in this network are using the correct subnet mask.